# Javascript error when using Google Visualization: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, grails, google-visualization

my project structure contains a simple index.gsp in which a template should be rendered. the template itself has several divs in which a chart should be drawn when rendering this template.
when i use the script below in any div in the index.gsp, the index view and chart will be rendered properly. but when i use the same script in the template, i get a blank page rendered and the javascript error below.

the template rendering is triggered by a formremote:

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" on404="alert('not   
found!')" update="content" url="[controller: 'charts', action:'generateChart']">
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

Script:

```
<div id="myID">
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});  
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawIt);               

function drawIt(){
    console.log("B");
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City',   'Population'],
        ['Berlin',      2761477],
        ['Freising',     1324110],
        ['Muenster',    959574],
        ['Muenchen',     907563],
        ['Neufahrn',   655875],
        ['Hof',     607906],
        ['Freiburg',   380181],
        ['Stuttgart',  371282],
        ['Kiel', 67370],
        ['Magdeburg', 52192],
        ['Erfurt',  38262]
    ]);

    var options = {
        height: 500,
        width: 700,
        region: 'DE',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
    };

    console.log("D");

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart('myID');
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: After you load template with formRemote, are your messages logged in console?

Comment: yes i have tested with some dummy console logs. the "B" inside the callback does not get logged when the error prompts

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the element to the chart API:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('myID'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1","packages":["corechart","table"]}]}'></script>
```

in the head.